# laravel with() method versus load() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I tried to understand the difference between the `with()` method and the `load()` method, but couldn't understand.

As I see it, using the `with()` method is "better" since I eager to load the relation. It seems that if I use `load()` I load the relation just as if I would use the `hasMany()` (or any other method that relates to the relation between objects).

Do I get it wrong?

Comment: related: eager loading and lazy eager loading [What is the purpose of the `loadMissing` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238937/laravel-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-loadmissing-function/47239442#47239442)

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Both accomplish the same end results—eager loading a related model onto the first. In fact, they both run exactly the same two queries. The key difference is that `with()` eager loads the related model up front, immediately after the initial query (`all()`, `first()`, or `find(x)`, for example); when using `load()`, you run the initial query first, and then eager load the relation at some later point.

"Eager" here means that we're associating all the related models for a particular result set *using just one query,* as opposed to having to run **n** queries, where **n** is the number of items in the initial set.

---

**Eager loading using `with()`**

If we eager load using `with()`, for example:

```
$users = User::with('comments')->get();
```

...if we have 5 users, the following two queries get run immediately:

```
select * from `users`
select * from `comments` where `comments`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

...and we end up with a collection of models that have the comments attached to the user model, so we can do something like `$users->comments->first()->body`.

---

**"Lazy" eager loading using `load()`**

Or, we can separate the two queries, first by getting the initial result:

```
$users = User::all();
```

which runs:

```
select * from `users`
```

And later, if we decide that we need the related comments for all these users, we can eager load them after the fact:

```
$users = $users->load('comments');
```

which runs the 2nd query:

```
select * from `comments` where `comments`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

...and we end up with the same result, just split into two steps. Again, we can call `$users->comments->first()->body` to get to the related model for any item.

---

Why use `load()` vs. `with()`? `load()` gives you the option of deciding later, based on some dynamic condition, whether or not you need to run the 2nd query. If, however, there's no question that you'll need to access all the related items, use `with()`.

---

The alternative to either of these would be looping through the initial result set and querying a `hasMany()` relation for each item. This would end up running **n+1** queries, or **6** in this example. Eager loading, regardless of whether it's done up-front with `with()` or later with `load()`, only runs **2** queries.

Comment: Thanks! I still have a question, why would I ever not use eager loading then and use the normal `hasMany()` method? (I think that a solution for my answer is that whenever I'm dealing with one user only, it doesn't matter whether I'm using the eager loading or not since it's gonna run 2 queries anyways?)

Comment: It depends on what data you're after. If you are only interested in the related model—comments, in our example—then simply query the `hasMany()` relation method: `$users = User::find(1)->comments;`, which would return only information about the comments, not the user. If, however, you also needed to access data from the initial model—the user—then `$user = User::where('id','1')->with('comments')->get();` will give you a collection that includes data from the User table *and* their related Comments. Either way, 2 identical queries are run, but the resulting collections are different.

Comment: Can `load` be nested like `with` can be? Like here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048804/get-related-data-through-relation

Comment: what does withitem() do?

Comment: I have noticed that a Model view relation for say a `User $user` and then calling `$user->with('posts')` will return all users and not the one from the model relation. Calling `$user->load('posts')` will give you that users posts.

Answer (score 13):

As @damiani said, Both accomplish the same end results—eager loading a related model onto the first. In fact, they both run exactly the same two queries. The key difference is that with() eager loads the related model up front, immediately after the initial query (all(), first(), or find(x), for example); when using load(), you run the initial query first, and then eager load the relation at some later point.

There is one more difference between With() & load(), you can put the conditions when using with() but you can't do the same in case of load()

**For example:**

```
ProductCategory::with('children')
        ->with(['products' => function ($q) use($SpecificID) {
            $q->whereHas('types', function($q) use($SpecificID) {
                $q->where('types.id', $SpecificID)
            });
        }])
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

@damiani Explanied difference between `load()` and `with()` as well but he said `load()` is not cacheable so I wanna say couple words about it.

Let assume we have a blog post and related with comments. And we're fetching together and caching it.

```
$post = Cache::remember("post.".$slug,720,function()use($slug){
   return Post::whereSlug($slug)->with("comments")->first();
});
```

But if there is a new comment and we want to display it immediately, we have to clear post cache and fetch post and comments together again. And that causes unnecessary queries. Lets think there are another queries for tags, media, contributors of the post etc. it will increase amount of resource usage..

```
public function load($relations)
{
    $query = $this->newQueryWithoutRelationships()->with(
        is_string($relations) ? func_get_args() : $relations
    );

    $query->eagerLoadRelations([$this]);

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see above when we use the method it loads given relation and returns model with fetched relation. So you can return it outside of a callback.

```
$post = Cache::remember("post.".$slug,720,function()use($slug){
   return Post::whereSlug($slug)->first();
});

$post = Cache::remember("post.relation.images.".$slug,720,function()use($post){
  return $post->load("images");
});

$post = Cache::remember("post.relation.comments".$slug,720,function()use($post){
   return $post->load("comments");
});
```

So if we load them seperatly, next time when some of them updated all you need to do clear specific relation cache and fetch it again. No need to fetch post, tags, images etc. over and over.