# what is the different between "with" and "load" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have go through the laravel  documentation, I didn't get the different between **With** or **Load** in queries, In which condition we need to use With or Load? Please describe it

```
Model::find(1)->with('firstModel','SecondModel');

Model::find(1)->load('firstModel','SecondModel');
```

Comment: Your question has answered in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005994/laravel-with-method-versus-load-method

Answer (score 5):

```
Model::find(1)->with('firstModel','SecondModel');
```

Isn't really doing anything at all, as `with` is a new builder now that isn't related to the model returned from `find(1)`.

```
Model::with(....)->find(1);
```

Would eager load the relationships.

```
Model::find(1)->load(...);
```

Is lazy eager loading. It is loading the relationships to an existing Model instance that you already have retrieved. (as `find(1)` is returning a Model instance and `load` is telling it to then load the relationships specified)
`load` can also be used on Collections to load relationships on all the Model instances contained. `load` is more useful when dealing with a set of Models compared to a single one as just using the dynamic property (lazy loading, if not loaded already) for a relationship on a Model would cause the same queries to be ran. On a set it removes any N+1 issue while iterating through them.

You can check out this article for some more information on this.

[asklagbox - blog - Eloquent Querying Relations](http://asklagbox.com/blog/eloquent-querying-relationships.html)

Answer (score 4):

In a nut shell, `with()` loads a relationship with parent model at the same time. That's eager load.

If you don't want to eager load that data, you can use lazy load or eager lazy load. In this case data will be loaded when you'll actually start to use relationship. So, you can decide at runtime what exactly relation you want to load or maybe you will not want to load any relationship data at all etc.

Answer (score 2):

`with()` loads with parent model at the same time.

`load()` used when you need [**Lazy Eager Loading**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading). For example, this may be useful if you need to dynamically decide whether to load related models:

```
$books = App\Book::all();

if ($someCondition) {
    $books->load('author', 'publisher');
}
```

If you need to set additional query constraints on the eager loading query, you may pass a Closure to the load method:

```
$books->load(['author' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('published_date', 'asc');
}]);
```