# Eloquent "with" method, how to rename return column name and how to return only one value

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I have one to many relationship between movie table and reactions table.

when I do this:

```
$query->with(['reactions' => function ($query){
            $query->where('user_id',Auth::id());
        }]);
```

I'm getting result like this:

```
{"id":1,"title":"Some title","description":"Some desc","reactions":[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"movie_id":1,"like":1}]}
```

My question is, how can I rename `reactions` column name to something else and how to return only, let's say, `like` column from `reactions` array.
I want return value to be:

```
{"id":1,"title":"Some title","description":"Some desc","somethingElse":1}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985900/eager-load-model-using-with-but-giving-it-another-name-laravel-5-2