# Can't load Post with Comment in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, load, comments

Theese are the relations:

Comment Model

```
class Comment extends Model
{

    /**
     *
     * The comment belongs to the post
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id')->with('Post');
    }

}
```

Post Model

```
class Post extends Model
{


    /**
     *
     * a post has many comments
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

then trying to check what passes:

```
$comment = Comment::findOrFail($id);

        return Response()->json($comment);

    }
```

Only the comment stuff is retrieved without relation, I don't understand, shouldn't it eager load the Post along the comment?

While if I remove the `->with('Post');` from Model and use

```
$comment = Comment::findOrFail($id)->load('Post');
```

The Post gets loaded but it should work with the Model method anyway.

Comment: No, I am retrieving one comment and there is only one post associated to the comment. I don't need any foreach. Besides as I already wrote in the main question $comment = Comment::findOrFail($id)->load('Post'); returns the comment with the post.

Comment: Ok got it. I think if you create dummy field using accessor then you can find your post easily. but it takes too many times for huge data.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change

```
$comment = Comment::findOrFail($id)->load('Post');
```

To

```
$comment = Comment::with('Post')->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: what's the difference ? The result is exactly the same.

Comment: @Chriz74 Ah I see what you mean you don't want to specify that it should load Post but it should be done automatically, but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Exactly. I did it with other Models and it works. Here's not working. Why? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you return a JSON object you have to do `Comment::with('Post')...` else it will not eager load the query (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

However, if you where to pass along the model object to the view `return view('welcome', compact('comment'))` you could call `$comment->post` and there's your Post object, lazy loaded.

Comment: I have other models where I am returning something->with('some_relation') perfectly fine to json

Comment: Thats exactly what im saying: you **have** to use `Model::with('relation')`

Comment: "Only the comment stuff is retrieved without relation, I don't understand, shouldn't it eager load the Post along the comment?" : No, it shouldn't. It only gets eager loaded using "with".

Comment: Exactly. Please read the code. In the Model I am loading comment->with('post') and it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to understand what your question is really. But yes, it should work as you say with `Comment::with('Post')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want that whenever a `Comment` is fetched, it's related `Post` be fetched along, just use the following attribute in `Comment` Model

```
protected $with = ['post'];
```

It should eager-load the associated `Post`

And yes, you need to remove `->with('post')` part from your relation. It won't do what you expect it to do.

In the meantime, I recommend reading a little about the difference between `with()` and `load()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005994/laravel-with-method-versus-load-method)

Comment: Hi, thanks, the way you suggested works too. Can you give a link to an explanation about this `protected` method you posted? Also, how do you explain that in the user model I have this: `public function collected_item(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Collected_item')->with('Item_model', 'Designer'); }` and it works ? It returns the collected_item with the relations.

Comment: Yes it'll... But it won't eager-load.... And about the protected method, I discovered it while following the `Model` class... I don't know of any resource as such... [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a38acf7ee2882d831a3b9a1361a710e70ffa31e/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L176)

Comment: hm, actually when I return a collected_item I get all the relations ('Item_model' and 'Designer'). So I don't understand why it doesn't work with Comment.. could it be due to the different relation? one is belongsToMany the other is belongsTo

Comment: I am sure it isn't because of that.. I think you have some other configurations done in the `User` Model.. I can be wrong..