# Get related data through relation

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am using laravel 5.5.13.

I have `App\Entity` which has many `App\Comment`'s and many `App\Thumb`'s.

Now I am able to fetch the Comments and Thumbs easily like this:

```
public function show(Entity $entity)
{
    return $entity->load('comments')->load('thumbs');
}
```

This gives data like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "kind": null,
    "name": "three",
    "created_at": "2017-11-01 04:29:22",
    "updated_at": "2017-11-01 04:29:22",
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "body": "no non o",
            "displayname_id": 4,
            "entity_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-11-01 05:16:14",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-01 05:16:14"
        }
    ],
    "thumbs": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "like": 0,
            "displayname_id": 5,
            "entity_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-11-01 05:16:39",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-01 05:16:39"
        }
    ]
}
```

*However*, I also need a list of the `$comment->displaynames()` and `$thumb->displaynames()` and also each comment has many `App\Vote`s via the `$comment->votes()`. Is it possible. I read lots on pivot but I am real confused.

My goal is to get data like this:

```
{
    // removed for concise (same as above)
    "comments": [
        {
            // removed for concise (same as above)
            "votes": [
                ..... // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I want to get this
            ]
        },
        {
            // removed for concise (same as above)
            "votes": [
                ..... // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I want to get this
            ]
        }
    ],
    "thumbs": [
        {
            // removed for concise (same as above)
        }
    ],
    "displaynames": [
        ..... // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I want to get this
    ]
}
```

We see here the new `displaynames` array and a `votes` array in each `comment`.

Do i have to use pivot here to in a one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller:

```
Entity::
with(['comments' => function($query){

    $query->with('votes');

}, 'thumbs' => function($query){

    $query->with('votes');

}])
->find($entity->id);
```

And relations:

```
entity has many comments
entity has many thumbs
thumb has many votes
comment has many votes
```

And you should tell more specific information about displayName relation...

**EDIT:**

```
Entity::
with(['comments' => function($query){

    $query->with(['votes', 'displayName']);

}, 'thumbs' => function($query){

    $query->with(['votes', 'displayName']);

}, 'displayName'])
->find($entity->id);
```

**EDIT-2:**

```
Entity::
with(['comments' => function($query){

    $query->with(['votes' => function($query){
       $query->with('displayName');
}, 'displayName']);

}, 'thumbs' => function($query){

    $query->with(['votes' => function($query){
       $query->with('displayName');
}, 'displayName']);

}, 'displayName'])
->find($entity->id);
```

Comment: Trying this out right now! Thank you sir! My displayname relation is, `displayname has many thumbs` and `displayname has many votes` and `displayname has many comments`.

Comment: Wow so so cool! It works! However one small thing, comment has votes, and votes have a displayname. So for each vote I need to show the displayname. Currently it is: `'comments' => function($q) { $q->with('votes')->with('displayname'); }`. The `with('displayname')` here is giving me comment's displayname. I also need the displayname for each vote. :(

Comment: Thank you sir so much for your edit!!! If you please add some comments I would love to upvote that as well. However `$query->with(['votes', 'displayName']);` is not working. It's still giving me the `displayName` of the `comment`. I need the displayName of each vote :(

Comment: It is OK :) Logic is very easy. It is copy and paste, recursively.

Comment: Oh my gosh!!! I can't believe I didn't see that pattern!!! That is so amazing, I learned so much here!! Thank you sir for such fast replys and such amazing solution!

Comment: Here is the awesome data I wanted to share with you - https://gist.github.com/blagoh/ee5e70dfe35aa5c68b2d445c63887aaa - I had a follow up question, is it ok if I posted another one and shared with you? This data has repeated entries for `displayname` (like "Harry" occurs in multiple places) which makes sense, but it would be awesome to flatten it all out. Is this possible in laravel, if it is I would love to post another question and accept your solution.

Comment: I created example of the flattened data - https://gist.github.com/blagoh/7076be06c400d04941a0593267e11e81/revisions#diff-cb567797700e4d4b63b106653162c671R15 - we see line 15 is now `"helpful_ids": []` and has just array of ids, and then all `displaynames` and `helpfuls` were moved to top of array on line 45 and 78.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in Laravel with Collections but your data is an output. I should try

Comment: Thank you sir very very much I will create topic :)

Comment: Posted the question, thank you so much! - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47058045/3791822

Comment: Hi there @umuttaymaz - I don't know why but `with` is not working for me for my implicit routes `show` function : `public function show(Pet $pet) { return $pet->with(['messages']); }`, do you know why `with` isn't working here?