# Flattening data with same performance for recursive $query->with

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.13.

Thanks to awesome help from awesome member of SO I currently get nested (and repeated) data by doing this:

```
public function show(Entity $entity)
{
    return $entity->with([
        'comments' => function($query) {
            $query->with([
                'displayname',
                'helpfuls' => function($query) {
                    $query->with('displayname');
                }
            ]);
        },
        'thumbs' => function($query) {
            $query->with('displayname');
        }
    ])->firstOrFail();
}
```

This gives me example data like this: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blagoh/ee5e70dfe35aa5c68b2d445c63887aaa/raw/a0612fb770a27eaacfbb1e87987aa4fd8902a8a3/nested.json

However I want to flatten it to this: https://gist.github.com/blagoh/7076be06c400d04941a0593267e11e81 - look at the version diff we see the changes:

https://gist.github.com/blagoh/7076be06c400d04941a0593267e11e81/revisions#diff-cb567797700e4d4b63b106653162c671R15

We see line 15 is now `"helpful_ids": []` and has just array of ids, and then all `displaynames` and `helpfuls` were moved to top of array on line 45 and 78.

Is it possible to flatten this data, while keeping same query performance (or better)?

Comment: Are you sure about your data? It looks corrupted. I can be wrong, but I am trying to map the result

Comment: The flat json data is corrupt on lines 44 and 77, I purposefully put `////` to bring attention. If we remove those lines it is good. :)