# Laravel: What is the purpose of the `loadMissing` function?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

The first sentence of the [Eager Loading section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) from the Laravel docs is:

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship
>   data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not
>   actually loaded until you first access the property.

In the last paragraph of this section it is stated:

> To load a relationship only when it has not already been loaded, use
>   the loadMissing method:

```
public function format(Book $book)
{
    $book->loadMissing('author');

    return [
        'name' => $book->name,
        'author' => $book->author->name
    ];
}
```

But I don't see the purpose of `$book->loadMissing('author')`. Is it doing anything here?

What would be the difference if I just remove this line? According to the first sentence, the author in `$book->author->name` would be *lazy-loaded* anyway, right?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Very good question; there are subtle differences which are not getting reflected instantly by reading through the documentation.

You are comparing "[Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)" using [`loadMissing()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L385-L392) to "Lazy Loading" using [magic properties](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L380-L393) on the model.

The only difference, as the name suggests, is that:

- "Lazy loading" only happens upon the relation usage.
- "Eager lazy loading" can happen before the usage.

So, practically, there's no difference unless you want to explicitly load the relation before its usage.

It also worths a note that both `load` and `loadMissing` methods give you the opportunity to customize the relation loading logic by passing a closure which is not an option when using magic properties.

```php
$book->loadMissing(['author' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('approved', true);
}]);
```

Which translates to *"Load missing approved author if not already loaded"* which is not achievable using `$book->author` unless you define an `approvedAuthor` relation on the model (which is a better practice, though).

---

To answer your question directly; yeah, there won't be any difference if you remove:

```php
$book->loadMissing('author');
```

in that particular example as it's being used right after the loading. However, there might be few use cases where one wants to load the relation before its being used.

---

So, to overview how relation loading methods work:

#### Eager loading

Through the usage of [`with()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L355-L360) you can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model:

```php
$book = Book::with('author')->find($id);
```

#### Lazy eager loading

To eager load a relationship **after** the parent model has already been retrieved:

```php
$book->load('author');
```

Which also might be used in a way to only eager load missing ones:

```php
$book->loadMissing('author');
```

Contrary to the [`load()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L368) method, [`loadMissing()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L385-L392) method filters through the given relations and lazily "eager" loads them **only if not already loaded**.

Through accepting closures, both methods support custom relation loading logics.

#### Lazy loading

Lazy loading which happens through the usage of [magic properties](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L380-L393), is there for developer's convenience. It loads the relation upon its usage, so that you won't be needing to load it beforehand.

---

@rzb has mentioned a very good point in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50074412/65732) as well. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks, great example with `"Load missing approved author if not already loaded"`. Just to make sure that I understood you right: Do you mean with `approvedAuthor` relation a method like this: `return hasMany('App\Author')->where('approved', true);` ?

Comment: Exactly. Regarding better readability and also to avoid duplicate relation definition, I would define it as: `return $this->author()->where('approved', true);`.

Comment: I also found another use-case. If you have to access a subrelation like `author.type` then without `loadMissing` you would generate a single query for each author.

Comment: One thing I am missing or misunderstanding here: why are these records missing?  Are they records that were skipped in a relation condition, and now we want to ignore the condition? Or perhaps records that have been newly inserted by another process while processing what has already been fetched?

Comment: @Jason I am with you on this one. I can't seem to understand why they're missing, or why you need to only load them if they are missing. I could see someone having a where statement when loading so that it only loads some of them, but if you want the rest wouldn't you just use the regular load statement again? Wouldn't the result be the same?

Comment: @sepehr Thank you for your explanation. But I have a question: Using `load` or `with` in this case can avoid N+1 problem, ist that correct? If we just use lazy loading via magic property, it can cause the N+1 because the author is loaded after.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the accepted answer is missing one important fact that may mislead some: you cannot run `loadMissing($relation)` on a collection.

This is important because most use cases of lazy eager loading relationships are when you already have a collection and you don't want to commit the n+1 sin - i.e. unnecessarily hit the DB multiple times in a loop.

So while you can use `load($relation)` on a collection, if you only want to do it if the relationships haven't already been loaded before, you're out of luck.

Comment: As of 5.6.22 you can now run loadMissing on a collection. https://medium.com/laravel-announcements/laravel-v5-6-22-released-5a3c821eebf7

Answer (score 2):

its mean do not repeat the query
to be clear about it
if you use : load() 2 times the query will repeat even if the relationships exists

while : loadMissing() is check if the relationship has loaded . it will not repeat the query . beacuse it has already loaded before by [ load() or with() ] = egear load

```
    DB::enableQueryLog();

    $user = User::find(1);

    // see the query 

    $user->load('posts');   
    $user->load('posts');  
    $user->loadMissing('posts'); // put it on top to see the difference 

    dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

that's what i think its purpose

Answer (score 2):

#### Very useful for APIs

The use of `with`, `loadMissing` or `load` can has more importance when use it in API environment, where the results are passed to `json`. On this case, lazy loading hasn't any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have multiple relationships.

book belongs to an author and book belongs to a publisher.

so first you might load it with one relationship.

```
$books->load('author');
```

and later on certain condition you want to load another relationship into it.

```
$book->loadMissing('publisher');
```

> But I don't see the purpose of $book->loadMissing('author');. Is it
>   doing anything here? What would be the difference if I just remove
>   this line? According to the first sentence, the author in
>   $book->author->name would be lazy-loaded anyway, right?

Suppose say

```
public function format(Book $book)
{
    //book will not have the author relationship yet  

    return [
        'name' => $book->name, //book will not have the author relationship loaded yet  
        'author' => $book->author->name //book will now have the author relationship 
    ];
}
```

Difference between above and below code is when will the relationship be loaded and how much control you have over the property.

```
public function format(Book $book)
{
    $book->loadMissing('author'); // book will now have the author relationship

    return [
        'name' => $book->name, // book have the author relationship loaded
        'author' => $book->author->name // book have the author relationship loaded
    ];
}
```

Comment: But since its eager loaded anyway, why would you do `loadMissing`? If you want access `$book->publisher` this will work with or without `loadMissing`.

Comment: @Adam see i improved the answer by explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers here have covered pretty well what the technical difference is, so I'd refer you to them first.  But the "why" isn't very evident.

Something I find myself preaching a lot lately is that Eloquent is really good at giving you enough rope to hang yourself with.  By abstracting the developer so far away from the actual SQL queries being produced, especially with dynamic properties, it's easy to forget when your database hits are hurting your performance more than they need to.

Here's the thing.  One query using an `IN()` statement on 1000 values takes about the same execution time as one query running on *one* value.  SQL is really good at what it does- the performance hit usually comes with opening and closing the DB connection.  It's a bit like going grocery shopping by way of making one trip to the market for *each* item, as opposed to getting it all done at once.  Eager-loads use the IN statements.

Lazy-loading is good for instances where you're handling too much data for your server's RAM to cope with, and in my opinion, not good for much else.  It handles only one entry at any given moment.  But it's reconnecting each time.  I can't tell you the number of times I've seen Transformer classes, which should be responsible only for reformatting data as opposed to retrieving it, leveraging those dynamic properties and not realizing that the data wasn't already there.  I've seen improvements as dramatic reducing execution time from 30 minutes to 30 seconds just by adding a single line of eager-loading prior to the Transformer being called.

(By the way, batching might be considered the happy-medium, and Eloquent's `chunk()` method offers that too.)

To answer your question a little more directly; if you're dealing with an instance where it's a one-to-one relationship, and it's going to be used in only one place, then functionally there is no difference between `load`, `loadMissing`, or a lazy-loading dynamic property.  But if you have a many-to-many, it may be worthwhile to gather up all that data all at once.  One book can have many co-authors.  One author can write many books.  And if you're about to loop through large sets of either, go ahead and make the most of your trip to the market before you start cooking.