# laravel eager loading using with() vs load() after creating the parent model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4, eager-loading

I am creating a **Reply** model and then trying to return the object with it's **owner** relation. Here is the code that returns an empty object:

```
//file: Thread.php
//this returns an empty object !!??
public function addReply($reply)
{
    $new_reply = $this->replies()->create($reply);
    return $new_reply->with('owner');
}
```

However, if i swap the *with()* method for *load()* method to load the **owner** relation, i get the expected result. That is the reply object is returned with it's associated **owner** relation:

```
//this works
{
    $new_reply = $this->replies()->create($reply);
    return $new_reply->load('owner');
}
```

i don't understand why. Looking for clarifications.

Thanks,
Yeasir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005994/laravel-with-method-versus-load-method here have a nice details of your problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you should use `with` when you don't have object yet (you are making query), and when you already have an object you should use `load`.

Examples:

**Collection of users**:

```
$users = User::with('profile')->get();
```

or:

```
$users = User::all();
$users->load('profile');
```

**Single user**:

```
$user = User::with('profile')->where('email','sample@example.com')->first();
```

or

```
$user = User::where('email','sample@example.com')->first();
$user->load('profile');
```

**Methods implementation in Laravel**

Also you can look at `with` method implementation:

```
public static function with($relations)
{
    return (new static)->newQuery()->with(
        is_string($relations) ? func_get_args() : $relations
    );
}
```

so it's starting new query so in fact it won't execute the query until you use `get`, `first` and so on where is `load` implementation is like this:

```
public function load($relations)
{
    $query = $this->newQuery()->with(
        is_string($relations) ? func_get_args() : $relations
    );

    $query->eagerLoadRelations([$this]);

    return $this;
}
```

so it's returning the same object, but it load relationship for this object.

Comment: excellent. The function definitions made it clear. So to achieve the same result as the **load** function one have to do it like: `return $new_reply->with('owner')->latest()->first()`. The important thing here is to understand that an already existing object is in fact a query builder that you can use to chain further. Thanks much for clarifying.