# laravel 5.5 model relation in json

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-response

I'm trying to understand, if in laravel 5.5 there is a method that given a model linked to another with an external key, I can obtain the result of the complete join of the attributes of both models. I wanto to avoid to return two models and merge them.

Below the code of my model:

```
class Event extends Model { 
     public function location(){
         return $this->hasOne('App\Location');
     }
 }
```

In the controller I obtain the location information of the respective Event, but in the result I would like to see information of both Event and Location.

In the controller If I call the model with the ORM:

```
  $event = Event::where('name',$name)->first()->location;

  $model=$eventLocation->getModel();
   return $model;
```

And obtain this json with

```
{"id":12,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"location_test","event_id":"1"}
```

That contains only the attributes of the location and not for the Event! How can I show both?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$event = Event::with('location')->where('name', $name)->first();
$location = $event->location;
```

In this way you will get the event itself and the complete related location as `location` field.

See the [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) section on the docs.

Comment: I obtain only the informations about location, nothings about the Event...

Comment: The event is inside `$event` variable you have a property `location` to access it. You can read all things using [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) methods like `toJson` or `toArray` on `$event` collection, like  `$event->toJson()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$event = Event::with('location')->where('name', $name)->first();

return $event->toJson();
```

You will have access to your event with `data.location`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$event = Event::with('location')->where('name',$name)->first();
```

or:

```
$event = Event::where('name',$name)->first();
$event->load('location');
```

Then when you just return model or call `$event->toJson()` you will have your `location` relationship loaded.

If you want to get details about loading relationships you can look at [laravel eager loading using with() vs load() after creating the parent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868744/laravel-eager-loading-using-with-vs-load-after-creating-the-parent-model/47868948#47868948)