# Weird behaviour of Eloquent One To One relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I need to get User with related Profile, but In case below the profile field is null:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
  return $request->user()->load('profile'); // { id: 1, ... profile: null }
});
```

But in this case the profile field is filled:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    $profile = $user->profile;
    return $user; // { id: 1, ... profile: { name: 'alex', ... } }
});
```

How can you explain this behavior and what is the correct way to load Profile in my case?

Relations:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}

public function profile(){   
    return $this->role == 'model' ? $this->hasOne('App\Models\Model\Profile') : $this->hasOne('App\Models\Client\Profile');
}
```

Comment: See this article to get idea of eager loading: https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-eager-loading

Comment: `return $request->user()->with('profile')` returns error "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 1):

**load() is Lazy Eager Loading**

Using load(), you nedd to run the initial query first, and then eager load the relation at some later point.  This is "Lazy" eager loading. lazy eager load a relationship after the parent model has already been retrieved.

[laravel with() method versus load() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005994/laravel-with-method-versus-load-method)

Comment: `return $request->user()->with('profile')` returns error "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 1):

Go through this for a clear view [Eager loading](https://www.amitmerchant.com/Laravel-Eager-Loading-Load-Vs-With/)

So to get relationship using with() it will run both queries at same time and will have relation attached to model collection but while using load() first we get the model then on some condition we use load to get relational data. e.g. :

```
      $users = User::all();   //runs first query

      if($condition) {
      $users = $users->load('organisations');  //lets assume organisations is relation here.
       //here runs the 2nd query
       }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `return $request->user()->with('profile')` returns error "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21611288)

Comment: @Cœur i am actually new to stackoverflow and not aware about these little things, Thanks for pointing out, will keep in mind for future.

Comment: @kshitij if you open the link "From Review" of my previous comment, you may be able to see that your answer will soon be deleted unless you improve it quickly.