# Including relationships in Laravel API resource response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

My aim is to create a book store API endpoint with a ratings relationship. The relationship between the Book & Rating is like this:

Book model

```
/**
* a book has many ratings
*/
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class, 'book_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
}
```

Rating model

```
/**
* a rating belongs to a book
*/
public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}
```

My BookResource looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

use App\Http\Resources\RatingResource;

class BookResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id'        => $this->id,
            'title'     => $this->title,
            'author'    => $this->author,
            'rating'    => RatingResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('ratings'))
        ];
    }
}
```

My RatingResource looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class RatingResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

I want to get all books along with the individual ratings and get a single book together with it's rating as well using both routes below in the api.php file:

```
Route::get('/books', function() {
    return BookResource::collection(Book::all());
});

Route::get('books/{book}', function(Book $book) {
    return new BookResource($book);
});
```

When I make a get request to `http://12.0.0.1:8000/api/books` on postman, I get all the books but the ratings are not loaded. The same thing happens when I make a get request to `http://12.0.0.1:8000/api/books/1`, the book is returned without the rating.

How are relationships loaded based on v5.7 [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping)

Comment: You didn't used load or with on fetching data, and wrote whenLoaded on the resource, So the result always be without rating, I think this link could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005994/laravel-with-method-versus-load-method

Comment: @honarkhah appreciate you pointing that out. Fixed it by using the lazying load `load()` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should make:
`Book::with('ratings')->get();` for the `/books` endpoint and 
`$book->load('ratings');` on `/books/{book}`.

Or, if you want to always load the relationship, define in the Book model:
`protected $with = ['ratings'];`

For more info, checkout Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 6):

Try to use

```
class BookResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            ...
            'rating'    => RatingResource::collection($this->ratings)
        ];
    }
}
```

or if you want to use `whenLoaded`

```
return BookResource::collection(Book::with('ratings')->get());
```

Answer (score 0):

As @honarkhah pointed out to me, I omitted loading the `ratings` when fetching `books` or a `book` so I fixed it by adding the `load()` when fetching the data like this

```
Route::get('/books', function() {
    return BookResource::collection(Book::all()->load('ratings'));
});

Route::get('books/{book}', function(Book $book) {
    return new BookResource($book->load('ratings'));
});
```