# How to retrieve data from two table in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have two DB tables.

**education_institutions**

```
id  institution_name  country  city    logo  description
1    ABC College       UK      London  null    null
```

**user_educations**

```
id  user_id  institution_id  grade   year  
1    1         1              3.2    2010
```

Relationships with both models are

**UserEducation**

```
public function educationInstitution()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EducationInstitution::class,'institution_id');
    }
```

**EducationInstitution**

```
 public function userEducation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserEducation::class,'institution_id');
    }
```

Now how can I retrieve all education institutions of a particular user with the institution details from *educations_institution* table.

I tried something like

```
public function getUserEducation()
    {
        $userEducation = auth()->user()->userEducation()
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();


        return response()->json([
            'userEducation' => $userEducation
        ]);
    }
```

But it retrieves only education institution id like:
I need user educations with corresponding institution details.
[image]

Comment: Please try searching before posting a new question, there are so many questions with answers and code to solve your problem here.  The docs (which should be the first thing you check before posting) are also the first result in a quick search. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005994/laravel-with-method-versus-load-method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with() function for relationship selection.

```
public function getUserEducation()
        {
            $userEducation = UserEducation::with('educationInstitution')->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
    
    
            return response()->json([
                'userEducation' => $userEducation
            ]);
        }
```