# Table relatioship laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, database, model-view-controller

I am doing a laravel project and I have to list users information.

I have the follwing tables in my phpmyadmin

table users

```
=======Users========
=     id    =  1   =
=    name   = test =
= office_id =  1   =
====================
```

Table Officies

```
========offices========
=      id     =   1   =
=     name    = admin =
= description =  ...  =
=======================
```

I have the following controller:

```
   public function users()
    {

        $users = User::all();
        $offices = Office::all();

        return view('admin.users')->with(['funcionarios' => $users,
            'offices => $offices
        ]);
    }
```

The following route:

```
Route::get('/admin/users', [\App\Http\Controllers\FuncionariosController::class,'users'])->name('admin.users');
```

The following HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">office</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr class="list-group-item-action bg-primary">
            <th scope="row">{{$funcionario->id}}</th>
            <td><a style="cursor:pointer;" class="checkuser  text-white"
                   data-id="{{$user->id}}">
                    {{$user->name}}
                </a></td>
            <td>{{$user->office_id}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want, instead of showing the office id,

```
 <td>{{$user->office_id}}</td>
```

the office table name. How can I achive this? I have used an if with a for each to achieve this, but is looks really cheap and not properly done.

Comment: Read up on [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: If you have a Relationship setup between `$user` and `$office`, then `$user->office->name`. Please read the documentation and setup the relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: But I don´t have the id, I am listing diferent users. They use find(id). My problem is creating that relatioship. I have read the documentation. But I am not able to make it work.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the documentation and following some basic Laravel tutorials. This is often one of the first things you will learn. 
Other than that, using the solution that John Lobo provided should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship) in `User` model

```
public function office(){

   return $this->belongsTo(Office::class);
}
```

and in your controller

```
 $users = User::with(['office'])->get();
```

and in your view

```
<td>{{optional($user->office)->name}}</td>
```

if you need only those users who has office assigned then

```
 $users = User::has('office')->with(['office'])->get();
```

Comment: Where is goes that return $this->belongsTo(Office::class);?

Comment: it map the office model to the user .please read documentation for better understanding

Comment: I know what it does, I don´t know how to apply it to my project.

Comment: @Maneneco .use it as i mentioned .it will work .if any error then let me kow

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I am not using it properly

Comment: @Maneneco .you might need to check log file or enable debugging mode. otherwise difficult to guess where it went wrong

Comment: Is enabled APP_DEBUG=true

Comment: @Maneneco check log file or debug line by line where it throwing erorr

Comment: change this line   return view('admin.users')->with(['funcionarios' => $users,
            'offices => $offices
        ]); to   return view('admin.users',['users' => $users])

Comment: I use return $this->belongsTo(Office::class); instead of   return view('admin.users')->with(['funcionarios' => $users,
            'offices => $offices
        ]); ?

Comment: no . that method you have to add in User model  and this line return view('admin.users')->with(['funcionarios' => $users, 'offices => $offices ]); to return view('admin.users',['users' => $users])

Comment: Yep, sorry, it worked out

Comment: is working without the with(['office'])->get(),  this has any security purpose?

Comment: @Maneneco https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005994/laravel-with-method-versus-load-method